# Regex to allow only alphanumerics with at least one character and no empty space

Tags: c#, model-validation

I keep trying everything from the search result (google) but without success till now.
For my username input I want only to allow alphanumerics, without empty spaces and no tabs. The username can have a combination of letters and numbers, but must have at least one character.
Can someone please share a regex able to do that, and with a bit explanation if some changes are required to be made later on.

Thank you in advance.

edit:
examples what should be allowed:"a012", "2342a", "anyalpha", "abc2xyz".
what should not be allowed: "1234123", " ace12", "any space", "space2 ", " space3"

Comment: it allows combination of numbers without alphabets

Comment: `\D+\S` maybe something like this?

Comment: when you say "it must have at least one character" do you mean one alphanumeric character, or one alphabetic character?

Comment: You should probably include examples of input that is allowed and not allowed.  The answers you are getting already demonstrates that your question is unclear about what is meant by "character".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?=\w*[A-Za-z])\w*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uMvcB1/2)

Comment: this works partly, I need also to ignore spaces wherever in the string (start, middle, end)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex => `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

^ start of line

[A-Za-z0-9]+ any character inside brackets , one or more times

$ end of line

This regex accepts only numbers and alphabetic characters and at least 1 character

Comment: OP didn't say it must *start* with an alpha character.  This fails on input that starts with a digit.    Try it on  9abcDEF